# Is there any way to simplify WebService's Async call

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services

I'm new to Silverlight development. 
I write a mini test application which authentificates on a server.
The communication i made through WCF WebServices.

To use the WebService's `Login(string, int)` method i must everytime use this sequence

1) initialize the a data member with a **EventHandler**

`_ltsCl.LoginCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(_ltsCl_LoginCompleted);`

where `var _ltsCl = new LoginToServerServiceClient();`

and   `LoginToServerService` is the WebService class

2) invoke the Async method

`_ltsCl.LoginAsync(txtUsername.Text, int.Parse(pbxPassword.Password));`

3) get results with

`_ltsCl_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e){}`

Is it possible to simplify this sequence in a way something like this

```
bool result = _ltsCl.Login(txtUsername.Text, int.Parse(pbxPassword.Password));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the complete callback as an anonymous method:

```
_ltsCl.LoginCompleted += (sender, e) => 
{
    var result = e.Result;
};
_ltsCl.LoginAsync(txtUsername.Text, int.Parse(pbxPassword.Password));
```

The syntax you have shown:

```
bool result = _ltsCl.Login(txtUsername.Text, int.Parse(pbxPassword.Password));
```

is possible only with the synchronous call which blocks the calling thread during the processing and returns the result once this processing has completed. It doesn't make any sense for asynchronous methods which return the control to the calling thread immediately.

But since synchronous blocking calls are forbidden in Silverlight you don't even have this possibility.